# SVN commands not working on Cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, svn, cygwin, tortoisesvn

I am trying to access a source code repository through CYGWIN, right after I have successfully checked out files through windows explorer, but it keeps giving me a 'host not found error in CYGWIN.

Trying to execute a `svn co` command for checkout in CYGWIN.

In the SVNTortoise network settings I have included my proxy server and username/password already.

Please let me know what I am missing here.
Below is the exact scenario from my cygwin bash while I am doing so:

```
bash-3.2$ cd
bash-3.2$ svn --version                                                                                                                                                                                   
svn, version 1.6.3 (r38063)
   compiled Jul  9 2009, 10:30:30

Copyright (C) 2000-2009 CollabNet.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.tigris.org/
This product includes software developed by CollabNet (http://www.Collab.Net/).

The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

* ra_neon : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using Neon.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme
* ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
  - with Cyrus SASL authentication
  - handles 'svn' scheme
* ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
  - handles 'file' scheme
* ra_serf : Module for accessing a repository via WebDAV protocol using serf.
  - handles 'http' scheme
  - handles 'https' scheme

bash-3.2$ svn co http://repositoryname/checkoutfile

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://repositoryname/checkoutfile': Could not resolve hostname `repositoryname': Unknown host (htp://repositoryname.com)
```

Comment: http changed to htp for escaping url posting restrictions! :D

Comment: I've formatted your output and re-introduced the missing 't's.

Comment: I'm looking for solution to this answer... did you get anywhere with it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, the Cygwin tooling won't use the proxy settings you've set up for TortoiseSVN.

Try setting the proxy in your shell before running the commands:

```
export http_proxy="http://<user>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>"
svn ...
```

If that works, you can add the `export ...` line to your `.bash_profile`.